# Is this considered DOM-XSS or self-XSS or both?

Tags: javascript, security, web, xss

**SCENARIO:**

A web page shows an error login page using these javascript lines

```
<script>
    let queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    document.getElementById("message").innerText = queryParams.get("message");
    let link = document.getElementById("link");
    link.innerText = queryParams.get("linkText");
    link.href = queryParams.get("linkUrl");
</script>
```

The last javascript line allows me to hide javascript inside a link in the web page crafting an url like the following.

https://vulnerablewebsite.com/folder/custom.html?message=not+correct?&linkUrl=javascript:alert(1)&linkText=click+here+to+shine

1) the user click the shortened version of this link

2) the user click "click here to shine"

3) the alert opens

I was inspired by this article on portswigger
https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/dom-based
in particular from this example

> If a JavaScript library such as jQuery is being used, look out for
>   sinks that can alter DOM elements on the page. For instance, the
>   attr() function in jQuery can change attributes on DOM elements. If
>   data is read from a user-controlled source like the URL and then
>   passed to the attr() function, then it may be possible to manipulate
>   the value sent to cause XSS. For example, here we have some JavaScript
>   that changes an anchor element's href attribute using data from the
>   URL:
>
> `$(function(){ $('#backLink').attr("href",(new`
>   `URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get('returnUrl')); });`
>
> You can exploit this by modifying the URL so that the location.search
>   source contains a malicious JavaScript URL. After the page's
>   JavaScript applies this malicious URL to the back link's href,
>   clicking on the back link will execute it:
>
> `?returnUrl=javascript:alert(document.domain)`

**QUESTION:**
to me they look the same kind of attack but someone told me it is a self-XSS. Anyway I read that self-XSS expects the user to self-paste javascript code in his console. So I'm confused and I'd like to know which type it is. Also, can be considered a vulnerability of medium/high severity or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming doesn't matter much, but

- It is definitely a vulnerability, according to CVSSv3 it would likely be a medium, but you can calculate yourself for this specific case.
- It is not self xss, you yourself showed a way via a link that if sent to a victim by an attacker would make the page vulnerable.
- It is definitely dom xss as it is entirely in javascript, no server roundtrip is necessary.